# Visual studio multi project template restore all nuget packages

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2015, vsix

I´m strugling around for some days with visual studio multi project templates installed by an vsix plugin.

What I tried:
[Stackoverflow 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857996/multi-project-solution-templates-for-visual-studio-2012-with-vsix-installer-an)
AND TONS OF MSDN ARTICLES

The problem/what I want to do:

1. Setup a private nuget feed for visual studio in general.
2. Install packages from this feed to the subprojects

I thought about using the nuget package restore command, because all the subprojects have their packages.config files but I have no plan how to run that command after the project was created.
Is there a way to start e.g. a powershell script that perform such tasks for me?

thanks & greetings
Nico

Answer (score 1):

If this is part of your own custom VSIX extension, you might want to consider using NuGet via C# itself via [NuGet.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Core/) or [NuGet.VisualStudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.VisualStudio/).

You could create your own IWizard and list the packages in the `<WizardData>` element in your `MyTemplate.vstemplate` definition file.

Although it is using the official NuGet v2 URL, I took this approach to make sure when ever users create a new ServiceStack project via ServiceStackVS, it installs the latest version across all the projects.

The [`NuGetPackageInstallerMultiProjectWizard`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS/blob/master/src/ServiceStackVS.NuGetInstallerWizard/NuGetPackageInstallerWizard.cs#L20) class is for use on multi-project templates and checks for the latest version of a specific NuGet dependency specified in the `<WizardData>` of the parent template. While the [`NuGetPackageInstallerWizard`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS/blob/master/src/ServiceStackVS.NuGetInstallerWizard/NuGetPackageInstallerWizard.cs#L20) is responsible for actually installing the NuGet dependency.

So if you know the URL users will need to use for the required NuGet packages you could take a similar approach.