# Visual studio template with nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've created a visual studio template.
The template contains nuget packages.

When I load the template nuget identifies all packages as installed (they appear in packages.config) but the files don't actually exist.

Is there a way to handle this?

And more thing, although I want it to work as the template loads, perhaps it is vital for analyzing the case: nuget restore doesn't solve the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331655/visual-studio-multi-project-template-restore-all-nuget-packages

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Nuget restore doesnt work for me (manually)  anyways ill try what mentioned in the post. Ill update with the results

Comment: I think this will work usually Nuget restore with in template has to be done via code(Either by .ps or C#).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. ill try it tomorrow

Comment: I tried the solution. Also found some MSDN articles about that issue. Still cant make it work. I'll update with the solution once I'll make it work