# nuget and vsix repo

Tags: c#, vsix, nuget-package-restore

I have exported a template project using the export tool in VS2015. I have created a nuget package which this project rely on.
In the vstemplate file I have added:

```
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>NuGet.VisualStudio.Interop, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>NuGet.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
  <WizardData>
    <packages repository="extension" repositoryId="ViSoftVSIXPackage.Visoft.87c53ff4-9d1f-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
      <package id="ViSoftCore" version="1.0.0" />
    </packages>
  </WizardData>
```

The repositoryId is the Id of the VSIX project.
In the VSIX project I have added the assets:

```
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="ViSoftCore.1.0.0.nupkg" d:Source="File" Path="Packages\ViSoftCore.1.0.0.nupkg" d:VsixSubPath="Packages" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate" d:Source="File" Path="ProjectTemplates" d:TargetPath="ProjectTemplates\HMIViSoft.zip" />
  </Assets>
```

Now, when i install the vsix, create a new project I get the following:
NuGet Package restore failed for project HMI.ViSoft4: Unable to find version '1.0.0' of package 'ViSoftCore.
When I go to Nuget Package Manager it says the package is installed but not able to find source.

I have tried this in many ways and I can't get this to work automaticly. If i manually create a package source in nuget package manager to c:\packagelocation everything is all good.

What am i missing here? Is this not supported? Do I write code in the vsix to create a package source in the nuget package manager?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue - **Step 11** highlighted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18858527/7292772) helped fix the problem. Basically this step ensures that a copy of nupkg file is created under `<template install path>/Packages/`